# Windows 7: How to have 2 shortcuts to the same executable in the Taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, shortcuts, administrator

One to be ran "as Administrator" and the other as the regular user?

Answer (score 0):

To create a shortcut in Windows 7 that would run as Administrator without triggering a UAC prompt, you create a task in Task Scheduler for it.

- [Run As Administrator Shortcut Without Password Prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/244959/run-as-administrator-shortcut-without-password-prompt/245043#245043)

If the item is a batch file, [How do I set up a desktop shortcut to a batch file which will run as administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/132679/how-do-i-set-up-a-desktop-shortcut-to-a-batch-file-which-will-run-as-administrato/132686#132686).

Good luck!

Comment: Oh dear, I just realized that [I also asked this exact question](http://superuser.com/questions/299451/start-a-service-or-services-with-a-double-click-without-the-uac-prompt) too.

Comment: P.S. Note that the "admin" shortcut points to `schtasks.exe`, so this shortcut and the "normal" shortcut can exist separately on the taskbar.

Comment: Actually, it's OK for it to trigger a UAC prompt.